# Selecting random position in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I have a numpy matrix that is randomly populated with zeros and ones:

```
grid = np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, size = (3,3))
```

Now I need to pick a random position inside this matrix and turn it to 2

I tried:

```
pos = int(np.random.randint(0,len(grid),1))
```

But then I get an entire row filled with 2s. How do I pick only one random position? Thank you

Comment: Select any random position or any random position that is also 1 or any random position that is also 0? For the former simply do : `np.put(grid,np.random.choice(grid.size),2)`.

Comment: Any random position. Your solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're just requesting only one random value for the indices instead of two random numbers (random). This one way of achieving your goal:

```
# Here is your grid
grid = np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, size=(3,3))

# Request two random integers between 0 and 3 (exclusive)
indices =  np.random.randint(0, high=3, size=2)

# Extract the row and column indices
i = indices[0]
j = indices[1]

# Put 2 at the random position
grid[i,j] = 2
```

Comment: Your solution helped me solve another problem in my code that I had no idea was related to the lack of indices. Thank you so much